# Raspberry Pi read ASCII from GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, uart, gpio

I have IR sensor connected to GPIO. When external signal reaches this sensor GPIO should return binary data in ASCII code.
This is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as io
io.setmode(io.BCM)

io.setup(15, io.IN)
def inputLow(channel):
   print('sensor hit');
   print(io.input(15));

io.add_event_detect(15, io.RISING, callback=inputLow, bouncetime=200)
```

Now I get from GPIO 15 only number 1 or 0.
In the instruction is written that when sensor is reached by external IR the data are automatically send by UART (GPIO15/RXD0). Data are sent as 32 byte array and is ended by `<CR><LF>`
How to read this data? Now I try like this:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200)
data =ser.readline()
ser.close()
```

but it returns only b''?

Comment: Please indicate what sensor it is, or add a link to its datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post

Comment: It still doesn't say which sensor it is...

Comment: This is the IR sensor, what type I don't know, I've written email to seller, now  it returns b''

Comment: um, 11520 is not a valid Serial baud rate. I think you meant `115200`. You also need to verify the speed on both ends, but I digress.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't verified that your device (or your connection) is functioning correctly. I would stop worrying about the Python code and spend some time doing basic diagnostics.  If you connect a terminal emulator (like `screen` or `miniterm` etc) to `/dev/ttyAMA0`
 do you see the expected information from the sensor?